# Looking to add in a Count query with Group by INTO an existing working query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

Goal:
I wish to get the Count of how many times a WorkItem was re-assigned 
From what I understand the proper query is the following:

```
SELECT      
    WorkItemDimvw.Id, 
    COUNT(WorkItemAssignedToUserFactvw.WorkItemAssignedToUser_UserDimKey) AS Assignments    
FROM  WorkItemDimvw INNER JOIN  WorkItemAssignedToUserFactvw 
ON WorkItemDimvw.WorkItemDimKey = WorkItemAssignedToUserFactvw.WorkItemDimKey 
GROUP BY WorkItemDimvw.Id
```

The EXISTING query is below and I'm wondering / forgeting if I should:

1. Just add in `COUNT(WorkItemAssignedToUserFactvw.WorkItemAssignedToUser_UserDimKey) AS Assignments`  since joins are existing, except it is group by WorkItemDimvw.Id
2. Should it instead be a subquery in the Select below?

Query:

```
SELECT 
    SRD.ID,
    SRD.Title,
    SRD.Description,
    SRD.EntityDimKey,
    WI.WorkItemDimKey,
    IATUFact.DateKey
FROM 
    SLAConfigurationDimvw 
    INNER JOIN SLAInstanceInformationFactvw 
        ON SLAConfigurationDimvw.SLAConfigurationDimKey = SLAInstanceInformationFactvw.SLAConfigurationDimKey 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN ServiceRequestDimvw AS SRD 
    INNER JOIN WorkItemDimvw AS WI 
        ON SRD.EntityDimKey = WI.EntityDimKey
    LEFT OUTER JOIN WorkItemAssignedToUserFactvw AS IATUFact 
        ON WI.WorkItemDimKey = IATUFact.WorkItemDimKey 
        AND IATUFact.DeletedDate IS NULL
```

Comment: Please, add input data and expected output.

Comment: What do you mean?  I'm just wanting to get an accurate COUNT added to the query and I'm wondering if I can just add in the Count statement, or if it needs to be added in as a subquery etc..

Comment: @ChadJacobs: you would need to show us sample data and expected output so we are sure to understand your requirement clearly. Please have a look at [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to aggregate the data on a sub query, before you join it.

```
SELECT 
    SRD.ID,
    SRD.Title,
    SRD.Description,
    SRD.EntityDimKey,
    WI.WorkItemDimKey,
    IATUFact.DateKey,
    IATUFact.Assignments
FROM 
    SLAConfigurationDimvw 
INNER JOIN
    SLAInstanceInformationFactvw 
        ON SLAConfigurationDimvw.SLAConfigurationDimKey = SLAInstanceInformationFactvw.SLAConfigurationDimKey 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    ServiceRequestDimvw AS SRD
        ON <you're missing something here>
INNER JOIN
    WorkItemDimvw AS WI 
        ON SRD.EntityDimKey = WI.EntityDimKey
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        WorkItemDimKey,
        DateKey,
        COUNT(WorkItemAssignedToUser_UserDimKey) AS Assignments
    FROM
        WorkItemAssignedToUserFactvw
    WHERE
        DeletedDate IS NULL
    GROUP BY
        WorkItemDimKey,
        DateKey
)
    IATUFact
        ON  WI.WorkItemDimKey = IATUFact.WorkItemDimKey
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 34
Incorrect syntax near 'IATUFact'.

Comment: above error is when I run separately , but then if I truly implement it I get `Invalid column name 'WorkItemAssignedToUser_UserDimKey'.`  of which I triple checked and it is the right column